# What object-type / class is the keyword "if"?

Tags: ruby, computer-science

If the words `true` and `false` are Boolean's, and anything within quotes are String's ("hey"), what object-type / class / etc. is `if`, `elsif`, `unless`?

This question isn't specific to Ruby necessarily, although I am more familiar with Ruby's syntax.

Comment: In Ruby `if`, `elsif` and `unless` are nothing more and nothing less than `keywords`. There is no definition of a keyword and no concept of a keyword as part of some grouping other than "keywords". A keyword is merely part of the language, just as classes and objects are. Incidentally, Ruby has no concept of a Boolean, even though we all know that is `true` and `false`, which are themselves instances, respectively, of the classes `TrueClass` and `FalseClass`.

Comment: You might be interested in the docs for [Ruby Syntax](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/syntax_rdoc.html) which explains the "building blocks" of a Ruby program, including _literals_ like `true` and `false` (which by the way are also [keywords](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/keywords_rdoc.html)) and _control expressions_ like `if`, `elsif` and `unless` (among others).

Comment: @CarySwoveland that doesn't necessarily make sense. I'm basically asking what defines the "if" keyword and you're telling me there is no definition? This is a computer language we're talking about, everything has a definition. Even the zero's and one's in binary have definitions and "why" behind them, the "if" keyword is (if you go far back enough), binary.

Comment: The use of the keyword `if` and other keywords that form control expressions are of course documented, but you asked, “what object-type / class / etc. is if, elsif, unless?”, and I am saying keywords, like classes, do not belong to any broader grouping. Perhaps I do not understand your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`if` is a [Control Expression](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html) (and less specifically a keyword).

These are language level constructs that steer the flow of a program and like the other control structures in Ruby (`else`, `elsif`, `case`, etc) `if` cannot be be passed and it's value is the result of evaluating the expression.

It doesn't have a type or class as it's not a value.

Comment: Ah I see! So it behaves _like_ a Boolean but _also_ directs which path the flow will continue on?

Comment: No - not really. A boolean is a value - singletons of TrueClass or FalseClass. if is a control flow and the return value is determined by the expression. For example `if rand(1..10).even?; :even; else :odd; end` will return either `:even` or `:odd`.

Comment: You could say that `if` directs the path _based_ on a boolean (i.e. truthy/falsy value of the condition)

Answer (score 4):

The question is non-sensical. (I don't mean this as an insult to the asker, but in a technical sense of the word.)

When you read a book, the story is created by "interpreting" the sentences on the page in your head. But the sentences on the page are not the story. This is like asking which character "if" in a Harry Potter book is. It isn't, it is just a syntactical part of the English language used to write the story.

This is what I mean by "non-sensical" above: it is a *category error*.

Same here. `if` is a *keyword*. Period. A *keyword* is a special syntactic construct that allows a parser to easier parse the syntax of the program. That is pretty much all there is to it. It is a part of the syntactic structure of the language, it is not a value in the running program.

Some (but not all) keywords, or more precisely, the expressions formed by those keywords, have specific *semantics* (meaning).

For example, the expression

```ruby
if some_condition then some_consequence else another_consequence end

# can also be written as

if some_condition; some_consequence else another_consequence end

# can also be written as

if some_condition
some_consequence else another_consequence end

# but is most commonly written as

if some_condition
  some_consequence
else
  another_consequence
end
```

has roughly the following semantics:

1. Evaluate the expression `some_condition`.
2. Let **C** denote the resulting value of that evaluation.
3. Execute one of the following steps:

   1. If **C** is *truthy*, i.e., **C** is not one of the two special values `nil` or `false`:

      1. Evaluate the expression `some_consequence`.
      2. Let **R** denote the resulting value of that evaluation.
   2. If **C** is *falsey*, i.e., **C** is one of the two special values `nil` or `false`:

      1. Evaluate the expression `another_consequence`.
      2. Let **R** denote the resulting value of that evaluation.
4. The resulting value of evaluating the entire conditional expression is **R**.

## Aside: where is this defined?

Unfortunately, unlike many other programming languages, the Ruby Language Specification does not exist as a single document in a single place. Ruby does not have a single formal specification that defines what certain language constructs mean.

There are several resources, the *sum* of which can be considered kind of a specification for the Ruby programming language.

Some of these resources are:

- The [ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html) – Note that the ISO Ruby Specification was written around 2009–2010 with the specific goal that all existing Ruby implementations at the time would easily be compliant. Since YARV and MacRuby only implement Ruby 1.9+ and MRI only implements Ruby 1.8 and lower and JRuby, XRuby, Ruby.NET, and IronRuby (at the time) only implemented a subset of Ruby 1.8, this means that the ISO Ruby Specification only contains features that are common to both Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9. Also, the ISO Ruby Specification was specifically intended to be minimal and only contain the features that are absolutely required for writing Ruby programs. Because of that, it does for example only specify `String`s very broadly (since they have changed significantly between Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9). It obviously also does not specify features which were added after the ISO Ruby Specification was written, such as Ractors or Pattern Matching.
- [The Ruby Spec Suite aka `ruby/spec`](https://github.com/ruby/spec/) – Note that the `ruby/spec` is unfortunately far from complete. However, I quite like it because it is written in Ruby instead of "ISO-standardese", which is much easier to read for a Rubyist, and it doubles as an executable conformance test suite.
- [*The Ruby Programming Language* by David Flanagan and Yukihiro 'matz' Matsumoto](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516177) – This book was written by David Flanagan together with Ruby's creator matz to serve as a Language Reference for Ruby.
- [*Programming Ruby* by Dave Thomas, Andy Hunt, and Chad Fowler](https://pragprog.com/titles/ruby4/programming-ruby-1-9-2-0-4th-edition/) – This book was the first English book about Ruby and served as *the* standard introduction and description of Ruby for a long time. This book also first documented the Ruby core library and standard library, and the authors donated that documentation back to the community.
- The [Ruby Issue Tracking System](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/), specifically, the [*Feature* sub-tracker](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-master/issues?tracker_id=2) – However, please note that unfortunately, the community is really, really bad at distinguishing between Tickets about the Ruby Programming Language and Tickets about the YARV Ruby Implementation: they both get intermingled in the tracker.
- The Meeting Logs of the [Ruby Developer Meetings](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14770). (Same problem: Ruby and YARV get intermingled.)
- New features are often discussed on the [mailing lists](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/community/mailing-lists/), in particular the [ruby-core (English)](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/ruby/ruby-core/index.shtml) and [ruby-dev (Japanese)](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/ruby/ruby-dev/index.shtml) mailing lists. (Same problem again.)
- The [Ruby documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/) – Again, be aware that this documentation is generated from the source code of YARV and does not distinguish between features of Ruby and features of YARV.
- In the past, there were a couple of attempts of formalizing changes to the Ruby Specification, such as the [Ruby Change Request (RCR)](http://rcrchive.net/) and [Ruby Enhancement Proposal (REP)](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby/wiki/Ruby_Enhancement_Proposals) processes, both of which were unsuccessful.
- If all else fails, you need to check the source code of the popular Ruby implementations to see what they *actually* do. Please note the plural: you have to look at multiple, ideally *all*, implementations to figure out what the consensus is. Only looking at one implementation *cannot possibly tell you* whether what you are looking at is an implementation quirk of this particular implementation or is a universally agreed-upon behavior of the Ruby Language.

Here is the definition of the *`if` expression* from the ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification:

> ## 11.5.2.2.2 The `if` expression
>
> ### Syntax
>
> *if-expression* ::
>       `if` *expression* *then-clause* *elsif-clause*<sup>*</sup> *else-clause*<sup>?</sup> `end`
>
> *then-clause* ::
>       *separator* *compound-statement*
>     | *separator*<sup>?</sup> `then` *compound-statement*
>
> *else-clause* ::
>       `else` *compound-statement*
>
> *elsif-clause* ::
>       `elsif` *expression* *then-clause*
>
> ### Semantics
>
> The *if-expression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Evaluate *expression*. Let **V** be the resulting value.
> 2. If **V** is a trueish object, evaluate the *compound-statement* of the *then-clause*. The value of the *if-expression* is the resulting value. In this case, *elsif-clause*s and the *else-clause*, if any, are not evaluated.
> 3. If **V** is a falseish object, and if there is no *elsif-clause* and no *else-clause*, then the value of the *if-expression* is `nil`.
> 4. If **V** is a falseish object, and if there is no *elsif-clause* but there is an *else-clause*, then evaluate the *compound-statement* of the *else-clause*. The value of the *if-expression* is the resulting value.
> 5. If **V** is a falseish object, and if there are one or more *elsif-clause*s, evaluate the sequence of *elsif-clause*s as follows:
>
>    1. Evaluate the *expression* of each *elsif-clause* in the order they appear in the program text, until there is an *elsif-clause* for which *expression* evaluates to a trueish object. Let
>       **T** be this *elsif-clause*.
>    2. If **T** exists, evaluate the *compound-statement* of its *then-clause*. The value of the *if-expression* is the resulting value. Other *elsif-clause*s and an *else-clause* following **T**, if any, are not evaluated.
>    3. If **T** does not exist, and if there is an *else-clause*, then evaluate the *compound-statement* of the *else-clause*. The value of the *if-expression* is the resulting value.
>    4. If **T** does not exist, and if there is no *else-clause*, then the value of the *if-expression* is `nil`.

And here is a link to the definition from the ruby/spec in [`language/if_spec.rb`](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/language/if_spec.rb)

Comment: The Harry Potter metaphor is excellent - control flow serves almost the same role as conjunctions in natural language.

Comment: "The question is non-sensical" : one immediately knows that Jörg W Mittag is about to strike again.

Comment: That's a good example, thank you for that! However, I guess I'm more asking what the definition of the keyword "if" is. For example, "we can say that Boolean values are represented with the notation of binary digits. Therefore, many times Boolean algebra is also known as the binary logic. However, Binary system is used to denote a system that is expressed in numerical notation that has base 2." True = "on" or 1, false = "off" or 0. [source](https://www.differencebetween.info/difference-between-boolean-and-binary)

Comment: @tofersApology: I added a quote from the ISO Ruby Language Specification to show how it is defined there. But it's not much different from my informal definition I posted yesterday. I also added a link to the definition in ruby/spec.

Answer (score 1):

Classes like "string" or "boolean" describe types of data. `if`, `else`, etc. aren't types of data but are usually known as "keywords".

Comment: Yeah, I know they’re keywords, and if they aren’t data types or objects, what are they? What is the keyword “if”?

Comment: It's control flow.  Imagine assembly code where you jump to another instruction pointer to execute code, it doesn't have a value it's just an operation.

Comment: @tofersApology: If you are reading Harry Potter, then is "if" a muggle or a wizard?

Comment: @JörgWMittag definitely a Wiggle (wizard + muggle).